# Как занести данные из двумерного массива в структуру

Tags: c, динамические-массивы

Вот код

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LEN 100

typedef struct words {
  char *mas;
}words;


int main()
{
    words *words_in=malloc(sizeof(words));
    //system("clear");
    int num_str = 0; //количество строк
    int k = 0;
    int sup = 0;
    int words = 0; // количество слов в тексте
    int sym = 0; // количество символов в тексте
    char str[LEN]; // 
    char arr[LEN][LEN]; // 
    char* istr;
    words_in->mas=malloc(sizeof(char)*sizeof(arr));
    //char *istr1;

    FILE* fp = fopen("test", "r");
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        if (fgetc(fp) == '\n')
            num_str++;
    }
    fclose(fp); 

    fp = fopen("test", "r");
    printf("\nТекст файла\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < num_str; i++) { 
        istr = fgets(str, LEN, fp);
        printf("%s", istr);
        for (char* istr = strtok(str, " .\t\n"); istr; istr = strtok(NULL, " .\t\n")) {
            strcpy(arr[k++], istr);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    fp = fopen("test", "r");
    printf("\nПодсчет количества слов в тексте\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < num_str; i++) {
        istr = fgets(str, LEN, fp);
        printf("%s", istr);
        for (char* istr = strtok(str, " \t\n"); istr; istr = strtok(NULL, " .\t\n")) {
            strcpy(arr[k++], istr);
            words++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    printf("\nКоличество слов в тексте = %d\n", words);
    printf("\nНахождение одинаковых слов\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < words; i++) {
        sup = 0;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < words; j++) {
            if (strcmp(arr[i], arr[j]) == 0) {
                sup++;
                printf("%s==%s, %d\n", arr[i], arr[j], sup);
            }
        }
    }
    //fclose(fp);

    printf("\nПодсчет количества символов в тексте\n");
    fp = fopen("test", "r");
    while (fgetc(fp) != EOF) {
        sym++;
    }
    printf("\nКоличество символов в тексте = %d\n", sym - 1);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Тут я сканирую текст из файла, разбиваю по словам, заношу слова в двумерный массив arr[LEN][LEN]. Но как мне выделить динамически память для arr и занести слова из этого массива в стуктуру?

Answer (score 2):

Я бы на вашем месте ограничился одномерным массивом

```
char ** arr = malloc(words*sizeof(char*));
```

А дальше просто вносил бы в него слова с помощью [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) -

```
arr[j] = strdup(найденное слово);
```

Если же вы хотите работать, не зная заранее количества слов - то тогда нужно сначала сделать небольшой массив и записывать слова, следя за границами массива. Исчерпался - вызываем `realloc`, добавляя память, и работаем дальше.

Добавлять лучше не по одному элементу, а, например, удваивая имеющийся объем - так будет эффективнее.

Comment: Да, количество слов в тексте неизвестно. И я не совсем понял, что вы имели ввиду, под arr[j]=strdup(найденное слово).  И ведь переменную words я узнаю лишь после того, как записал все данные в двумерный массив и прошелся по нему.

Comment: Тогда через `realloc`, отслеживая, сколько незанятых мест еще есть в массиве. Что я имею в виду под `strdup`? Что эта запись заменяет текст `arr[j] = malloc(strlen(word)+1); strcpy(arr[j],word);` - если не хотите использовать `strdup`, пишите так...

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас попробую с одномерным массивом, как то пробовал с ним, но не получалось. И получается сначала я выделяю память char ** arr = malloc(50*sizeof(char*)); (так как words у меня еще неизвестно, я выделю для начала 50). Затем проверяю массив на переполненость, и если переполнено, вызываю realloc, так?

Comment: Если при очередном добавлении будет переполнено, а пока всего лишь заполнено под завязку :) Если уже переполнено - что-то делать поздно...